# Recurly API returning 500 error

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, recurly

I am following the example code snippets [the one in the right panel here](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-subscription). So I have a Recurly token and am trying to start a subscription using it.

```
    subscription = Subscription()
    subscription.plan_code = 'monthly'
    subscription.currency = 'USD'

    account = Account(account_code='1a')
    account.email = 'mark@example.com'
    account.first_name = 'mark'
    account.last_name = 'lname'

    billing_info = BillingInfo()
    billing_info.number = '4111-1111-1111-1111'
    billing_info.month = 1
    billing_info.year = 2019

    account.billing_info = billing_info
    subscription.account = account

    subscription.save()
```

I get error 500 when the code above runs. If I comment out `subscription.save()` the logs show `ParseError: mismatched tag: line 6, col 2` which seems like xml parsing error. I get no error(but of course I presume the subscription is not being saved). Could this error be  as a result of testing many times? or what could be the issue? am using sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I was missing `recurly.SUBDOMAIN` together with `recurly.RECURLY_API_KEY` settings. All `save()` methods for `recurly.Subscription(), recurly.BillingInfo(), recurly.Account()` were throwing the error when called.